# Playing video on www.foxsoccer.tv does not work

Tags: 11.10, firefox, video

How can I play video through www.foxsoccer.tv?   I don't have problems with playing video, i.e. watching live events on espn, but on the foxsoccer website it just shows the loading video icon and never plays. Are there any options I can choose in Mozilla or in my operating system:  11.10?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that may - or may not - apply to your situation.  There is a plugin for Netscape to help you find if you are using the "best" version of Flash for your system; it's called Flash-Aid.  You can install it following the instructions here: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/11/flash-aid-helps-you-install-adobe-flash-player-in-ubuntu-64-bit-32-bit/

Once installed, run it and accept all the defaults.  After, restart Firefox and see if it will run your site.  If not, you can uninstall the plugin easily from Firefox by choosing Tools->Add-ons from the Firefox menu.

In my case, I thought I had the "best" Flash already on my system (11.10), but there was one site in particular that I couldn't run until I used Flash-aid.  I hope it works for you, too.

Comment: Actually in most cases, Flash-Aid does not solve problems, it only installs in an easier way the Flash Plugin, but truly, how easy can something get that with one click on the Ubuntu setup or one click on the software center you can install it already.

Comment: No, Flash-aid doesn't actually solve problems, but what to install from the repositories is not very clear.  (In fact, I would argue that it is decidedly unclear, especially to relatively new users.)  I thought I had done it correctly, but it turned out I had not.  Nobody was able to tell me why I was unable to run a particular site, but Flash-aid provided the answer.

Comment: Just so I learn na dif you can, can you give me an example on how you had trouble installing Flash so I can provide next time a better answer for installing Flash.

Comment: Installing was easy enough: knowing what to install was not.  I read quite a few answers on AskUbuntu and also looked at the options in the repositories and tried to choose correctly, but nothing was really all that clear.  And when I did choose and tried it out, everything seemed to work, so I thought I had installed the correct version.  The one site that didn't work was not enough to cause me to think that Flash was to blame.

Answer (score 0):

If videos show correctly in places like youtube, vimeo, espn and others and not in foxsoccer this is an issued with that site and not firefox or Ubuntu 11.10. If not then you might have a flash problem but as you stated, watching videos in espn works so am going for the foxsoccer site having an issue.

What I suggest is:

1. Check that the site does not have some sort of geolocation service that might banned or limit your country. Personally is just dumb to have something like that.
2. Check to see there is a maximun allowed of viewers for the video you want to watch. Bandwidth and such.
3. Check to see that for some specific super top secret fox soccer chance, the site asks to login, to install something additional or anything not common in video, streaming or live sites. This is just an idea in the air but some sites ask to have "something" installed that they use to monitor activity (Which is not even related to the actual watching of the video but anyway).

Comment: This is exactly the issue that I was facing, too.  Everyone told me the problem was with the site, or maybe with Flash.  I could play YouTube, Vimeo, and everything else: it was just the one site.  FlashAid might seem silly, perhaps, but it was the only thing that "solved" the problem.  It's easy, entails no cost to someone's system, and just might work.